# Bug with Tab Bar being covered by UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard, uitabbaritem, xcode-storyboard

So I have 3 main scenes, each with a tab bar item.  The first scene (Account scene) contains a UITableView.  Also on this scene I have a button which switches to a different scene that is NOT included on the tab bar.
ie. Account scene (which IS on tab bar) has button to link to Account Info page (which IS NOT on tab bar).  This all works fine, but when I go back to the Account scene from the Account Info scene, the UITableView now is covering the Tab Bar (or the Tab Bar may have just disappeared altogether), so I can no longer access it and switch to different scenes.

Anyone else encountered something similar or know why this may be happening?  If sample code is needed I can post some, but I did this mostly using storyboard.

Cheers,

Robin

Comment: Fixed.  Was segue-ing to the view itself, instead of segue-ing to the TabBarController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Was segue-ing to the view controller itself, instead of segue-ing to the TabBarController that handled the view.  Limitation is that I can only segue back to the first tab bar view, which is kind of annoying but oh well.